# Random variable with partially unknown distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, reference-request

> This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.

This is just bad will, I highlighted the question in bold.

**Has there been any work done about random variables that have a "partial density" $f$ such that $0<\int f<1$ and the rest of the mass is distributed in an unknown way (outside of the support of $f$)?**

I am curious as to what can be said about such random variables and if there are ways of estimating the unknown part. And in what frameworks can such incomplete random variables still be useful.

> This question should include more details and clarify the problem.

I would like to know if anyone has heard of random variables with incomplete information about their distributions. It's not complicated. Let $X:\Omega\rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a function on some sample space $\Omega$. Say $X$ has partial density if for $\omega$ such that $X(\omega)\in\left[-\sqrt{1/\pi},\sqrt{1/\pi} \, \right]$  then $X$ has local distribution $f(x)=\sqrt{1/\pi-x^2}$ (a half disc of radius $\sqrt{1/\pi}$). We have $\int\limits_{-\sqrt{1/\pi}}^{\sqrt{1/\pi}} f(x) \, dx=1/2$. So $\Bbb P[X\notin[\sqrt{1/\pi},\sqrt{1/\pi}]=1/2$ but we don't know how it is distributed in this subset.

For example consider a die that you throw on a table that has a hole. The hole leads to a tube that splits into $4$ tubes labeled $7,8,9,10$. The possible values taken by $X$ are $1,2,\dots,6$ if it the die doesn't fall into the hole and $7,\ldots,10$ if it falls into it and depending on which subtube it enters you get a number. And suppose you don't know how the die is weighted but you do know $\Bbb P[X=7]=P[X=8]=P[X=9]=P[X=10]=1/10$.

I guess this is more of a statistics question now.

Comment: I feel that it might be helpful if you have some idea of what you want to do with the definition. For example, in information theory there are channels such as Z-channel which does something similar (not exactly the same) in the discrete setting, and the goal is to study properties such as the channel capacity etc.